# Combinatorics and Latin squares

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

Let's have two Latin squares, in this case, the two which are shown in this question.
If we superimpose them we get 34 different combinations, with two repetitions, namely 4B and 1E. Can someone find two Latin squares, which when superimposed have fewer than two repetitions?

[image: GLsquare]

Comment: If a combination appears with any other frequency than 1, *it is **not** a Graeco-Latin square* by definition. As for whether you can have less than two repetitions in the design, look up Euler's soldiers...

Comment: To start with, you will need to make sure your square has a different number of rows/columns than 6

Answer (score 1):

Neither B1 nor E4 appear at all, as a result of B4 and E1 appearing twice. One of the two coordinates for each pair has been permuted with the other pair. Since repeating that permutation would return the original pairs, it is of order 2.

Since the shortest odd permutation that is not identical is order 3, and a permutation identical to a Graeco-Latin square of order 6 is impossible, you cannot make a square that has fewer repeated pairs (or missed pairs) than shown.

Comment: After receiving your comments, I will rephrase the question.